# Singleton pattern for a property in c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I am trying to adapt singleton policy for my CsvConfiguration Property.

If the configuration is already available, just return the configuration. else, get the configuration and return the same and I am able to build this code.

```
    public Rootpdf pdfConfiguration
    {
        get
        {
            Rootpdf pdfConfiguration = null;
            try
            {
                if (pdfConfiguration == null)
                {
                    //retrieve the configuration file.
                    //load the configuration and return it!
                }
                else
                {
                    return pdfConfiguration;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error("An error occurred while reading the configuration file.", e);
            }

            return pdfConfiguration;
        }
    }
```

Advantages (i hope): Whenever my pdfConfiguration is wanted, if already it is available, i can return it. Need not load the configuration file eachtime
and calculate the configuration.

My Query: The resharper! The resharper tells that the code

```
   if (pdfConfiguration == null) //The expression is always true.
```

Is it really a problem with resharper that it doesn't understand I am following this singleton pattern ?

or

Am I not following singleton pattern at all?

Comment: The `pdfConfiguration` is only a local variable assigned to `null`, not a persistent member. It would be also way easier to just use `Lazy<T>`...

Comment: This is not the singleton pattern...

Comment: This is the FailAtLazyLoad:EraseAllInformationAndThenLoadItAllAgainBecauseYouJustCanPattern™

Comment: this is not singleton which is not a pattern: it's an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Killercam: sorry, If my understanding is wrong. According to me, singleton pattern returns something if not already available. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: See my answer below. It will show you how to set up the Singleton 'pattern'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

think you have to use a local variable out of the getter

```
    private static Rootpdf  _pdfConfiguration ;
    public static Rootpdf pdfConfiguration
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                if (_pdfConfiguration == null)
                {
                    //retrieve the configuration file.
                    //load the configuration and return it!
                }
                else
                {
                    return _pdfConfiguration;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error("An error occurred while reading the configuration file.", e);
            }

            return _pdfConfiguration;
        }
    }
```

and as you want a singleton, i made it a static property... hope it's what you need.

Comment: "as you want a singleton, i made it a static property... hope it's what you need." +1

Answer (score 7):

You're setting the singleton to null at the top of your get clause:

```
Rootpdf pdfConfiguration = null;
//THIS IS THE PROBLEM.
```

Note: 99% of the time, ReSharper **is** smarter than you. I don't like it, but it's true.

Comment: The problem is if I don't do that I get an error stating "variable might not be initialized"

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. It should run fine, I think.

Comment: Yes, as soon as It was moved outside the property.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what your class should look like:

```
public class RootPdf
{
    private static RootPdf instance;

    private RootPdf()
    {
        //retrieve the configuration file.
        //load the configuration and return it! 
    }

    public static RootPdf Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    instance = new RootPdf();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.Error("An error occurred while reading the configuration file.", e);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how you will call the object:

```
var pdf = RootPdf.Instance;
```

Answer (score 1):

This line: `if (pdfConfiguration == null)` will always be true due to this line (just before) `Rootpdf pdfConfiguration = null;`. What you need to do is to place the last line (`Rootpdf pdfConfiguration = null;`) outside the `Get` method. This will stop the variable to be initialized to null each time.

```
private static Rootpdf pdfConfiguration = null;
public Rootpdf PdfConfiguration
{

    get
    {            
        try
        {
            if (pdfConfiguration == null)
    ....
```

More information on the Singleton Pattern is available [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Alternatively, you can use a [Static Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx):

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to
>   perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only. It
>   is called automatically before the first instance is created or any
>   static members are referenced.

```
public class Foo {
private static Rootpdf pdfConfiguration = null;
static Foo()
{
    pdfConfiguration = ....
}
public Rootpdf pdfConfiguration
{
    get
    {
        return pdfConfiguration;
    }
 ....
```

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: As per your edit suggestion, I have updated my answer.

Comment: +1 for the static constructor too.. Am i just accepting the other answer because of his low reputation.. Thanks for the great answer.. :)

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: No worries :).

Answer (score 1):

```
class MySingletonClass 
{
    private static UserSettings instance = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default protected constructor.
    /// </summary>
    protected MySingletonClass()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoke the singleton instance.
    /// </summary>
    public static MySingletonClass Instance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new MySingletonClass();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

This woud be invoked/instanciated like

```
MySingletonClass msc = MySingletonClass.Instance();
```

You can also use an accessor/Property to return the instance

```
public MySingletonInstance Instance
{
    get 
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new MySingletonInstance();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Where this is invoked/instantiated via

```
MySingletonClass msc = MySingletonClass.Instance;
```

I like the first method of the above.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned this is a not a singleton pattern.

If you want to stick with the idea you described then I would change your code to :

```
internal class Config
    {
        private readonly Lazy<Rootpdf> _config;
        public Config()
        {
            _config = new Lazy<Rootpdf>(ReadConfiguration);
        }

        private Rootpdf ReadConfiguration()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


        public Rootpdf pdfConfiguration
        {
            get
            {                
                try
                {
                    return _config.Value;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.Error("An error occurred while reading the configuration file.", e);
                }

                return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays , I think since C# 6.0, you can use initial values with properties, like this:

```
static public Rootpdf pdfConfiguration { get; } = new Func<Rootpdf>(() => {
    //retrieve the configuration file.
    //load the configuration and return it!
    return new Rootpdf();   // Something like this perhaps..?
})();
```